# SSRS border lines with different colors not overlapping properly

Tags: reporting-services, report, border, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-2014

I have a user-designed report that I am trying to replicate in SSRS, the report has a table with a default border color **(Gray)**.

I need to draw a black line through one column, this adds the effect of separating the columns that lead up to the final column.

The problem I have is that the black line is not consistent but looks "split up" by the grey border of the table(and its cells).

The control used is a Tablix.
The workaround we have is to make the whole report color black or gray, but I'm just asking this to see if there is a way to implement different colors in an aesthetic way.

[image: Image of table with split black column]

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by removing thick border and adding a BLANK column where you want the thick line.

Make the width of the column as per your requirement and make the borders to none for these cells (of blank column added). You may play with your left and right cells (it can be done). also, You should make the Can grow and Can shrik to False and True respectively.

If you want complete dark line (as shown), you may get an exception on the last row of the border for this particular added column. You can create a Report variable and keep the totalRecordCount and use it in expression of down border. Hope it helps!

[image]